# Unable to install HP Laserjet 1106 on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, printing, hp

I am unable to use my HP Laserjet P1106 on Ubuntu 20.04 / Ubuntu 20.10. I have tried all the resources to install printer via USB and as a network printer. My working is dependent on printing, I have more than 7 HP 1106 printers installed in my workplace, cant afford to change them.

Kindly any one suggest the way out. Seems HP is not supporting printer on Ubuntu. But my printers works well with win xp / win 7 / win 10 .

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. Problem is due to python 3 installed in my system, to update please follow following steps
Purge and re-install python 3.8
ls /usr/bin/python*
Remove both configuration and/or data files of python3.8 and it's dependencies
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python3.8
install new version of python
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python3
If required install all other dependencies 
Download and install hpdrivers and plugins (both should be same version)
https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/plugins